# How do I change the default name for the Title column? (SharePoint 2010 Foundation)

Tags: 2010

Somehow I actually did change the default name for "Title" - now in all my lists and anywhere it should say "Title" it now says "Name".  I changed it for an individual list somewhere along the line and changed the default instead.  So, how do I change it back to say "Title"?

I am just playing with a test site. Is it possible to reset the entire site back to default settings?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chances are you changed the Item site content type, which all lists inherit from. Go so Site Settings > Site Content Types, find the Item and you should be able to name it back.

Comment: and to piggyback, if you want to change it, you can, but you have to change it down at the list level to something more suitable for the need.